# Twitter API not responding with whole tweet

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am creating a Twitter API but the API isn't returning the whole tweet, it seems to stop when their is a link in the tweet. I am using PHP with TwitterAPIExchange.php, how can I fix this?

Example:

> Ingewikkelde antwoorden op vragen van @AgnesMulderCDA over de #waakvlam van de #NAM. De NAM hoeft pas in november t… https:// t.co/ZM0Tuk9AYv

Should be this: https://twitter.com/SGaster/status/849334531907887104

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = '?q=#kamerwatch';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest();

$print = (json_decode($response));
print_r($print);
```

Comment: Can you please post a code example that returns the tweet?

Comment: I've edited it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add `tweet_mode=extended` on your request

example :

previous url : https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=booty&count=50

correct url : https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=booty&count=50&tweet_mode=extended

and for getting the text use `full_text` instead of `text` key.

more detail here --> https://twittercommunity.com/t/truncated-text-and-media-entities-not-returned/74358

Comment: I'll test it if i am home! Thank you very much!!

Comment: It workes fine! only by RT's not. Is this possible to fix?

Comment: you mean you're not getting retweet's text?

Comment: I mean that by a Retweet it gaves not the hole tweet, see the example:

Comment: RT HenkStrikkers: #Kamerwatch Vandaag sprak lisawesterveld #maidenspeech uit over toetsen en ruimte voor leraren. Terugkijken hier https:…

Comment: for getting the retweeted text you have to parse the `retweeted_status` key inside of this key you have another key `full_text` which contains full tweet text.